# Is it possible to use python code to open another application?

Tags: python

i am wondering if it is possible to open an app with python. I did some googling but i did not find anything that works. I tried:

```
import os
os.system("Settings")
```

and

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe")
```

but these do not work and i cant find anything else

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `subprocess.run()` work?

Comment: The second one should work, although `subprocess.run()` is probably a better fit. What's the result you're getting?

Comment: "Does not work" doesn't tell us enough to say anything about _why_ it didn't work. You need to tell us what specific error is thrown, not just that you didn't get the behavior you wanted.

Comment: Might need to escape the \'s in your path. `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steam.exe"`

Comment: ...or use a raw string (`r'c:\...'`)

Comment: `I did some googling` - did you read through the Python documentation practicing the examples and looking to see if any of those examples could be adapted to your needs?

Comment: BTW, instead of "settings", you can execute a .cpl file to open a Windows control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't work because the format of the path is wrong

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steam.exe")
```

**or**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe")
```

Comment: And this is a good step for OP to add to the process.  When that line didn't work, one of the first things you could do is just run `print(os.path.exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe"))`.  If you get False, you should suspect there's a problem with the path formatting.

Comment: Yes, I know right